# Can you access EMRFS from Hadoop on EC3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Is access to EMRFS limited to EMR, or can be it accessed from Hadoop installed on EC2. 
Can anyone point to some article on how AWS manages the transfer of data from S3 to Hadoop cluster for processing. How is EMRFS more efficient as compared to S3a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EMRFS is an implementation used to access s3 by EMR and, therefore, you will not be able to use it with hadoop installed with EC2.

With Hadoop on EC2, you will have to use the hadoop-aws module (which contains s3a).

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Overview

Performance wise, I am not sure if there are major differences or implications. (this is very subjective and you may have to do performance tests to validate this). But there is one major difference between emrfs and s3a. EMRFS offers strong consistency for some time now. This is very helpful where you need read-after-write consistency (like HBASE and other applications).

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-consistent-view.html

Please note that apache Hadoop also has built a similar strong consistency model with s3guard.

- https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.3/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/s3guard.html

General rule of thumb is to use EMRFS when using EMR and s3a implementation when using other hadoop distros.